# GLFW. Как работать с функцией glfwGetWindowMonitor ? ( Как сделать полноэкранный режим )

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

Читаю документацию на сайте:

https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#window_monitor

Там есть функция `GLFWmonitor* monitor = glfwGetWindowMonitor(window);`
И там описано мол:

For windowed mode windows, this function returns NULL. This is how to tell full screen windows from windowed mode windows.

Как я  понял, что бы был полноэкранный режим эта функция должна возвращать не NULL ??
Если так то как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

вот так вот в фулл screen

```
GLFWmonitor* primary = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();
const GLFWvidmode& mod = *glfwGetVideoMode(primary);
glfwSetWindowMonitor(m_window, primary, x, y, mod.widith, mod.height, mod.refreshRate);
```